# Is $[0, 0.5)$ an open set in metric space $[0, 1]$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, intuition

I am learning topology and have a question. In the metric space $[0, 1]$, with the usual definition of metric, and the topology generated by the metric, I think sets containing one of the end points and open on the other end, such as $[0, 0.5)$, should be open sets, since by definition of open ball in metric space, the open ball about point $0$ is $[0, x)$. But this is a little counter-intuitive, so just want to confirm with people knowledgeable in topology, is this correct?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The set $[0,1/2)$ is indeed an open subset of $[0,1]$.

An equivalent statement is

> The set $[1/2,1]$ is a closed subset of $[0,1]$

which may feel a bit more intuitive.

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote, it's correct.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Isn't that quite useless in explaining the situation? What if $X = [0,1)$?

Comment: @ArcticChar Then $X$ is open iff $[1,1]=\{1\}$ is closed, and the latter may indeed (in my opinion) feel more intuitive. Keep in mind that the OP already has the right argument, they're just checking because it's rather counterintuitive.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I mean what if the metric space is $[0,1)$. Then arguing that $[0,1/2)$ is open since $[1/2, 1)$ is closed is not helping.

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes, there are spaces for which this idea doesn't help. But this question asked about a *specific* space, and it does help for that space. I think it's absolutely fine to bring up heuristics intended to make a particular example clearer; there's no claim that this should always be helpful.

Comment: But the exact argument in the OP works well with $X= [0,1)$ as well. I even feel the answer provided in this answer is the wrong intuition. @NoahSchweber

Comment: @ArcticChar Actually it's getting at a very important piece of intuition: that while the notion of *openness* plays a bit counterintuitively with a closed subspace, the notion of *closedness* plays very well with a closed subspace. Similarly, to understand why $(0,1]$ is closed in $(0,2)$ it's easier to think about why $(1,2)$ is open in $(0,2)$, and this gain in simplicity is due to the fact that openness plays better with *open* subspaces than closedness. And subspaces which are neither open nor closed have to be treated with care. I really don't think there's anything at issue here (cont'd)

Comment: especially given that "shifting attention to the complement" **is** often a helpful thing to do. I think we'll have to agree to disagree on this point.

Comment: Thanks to all posters for the helpful answer and discussions.